# How does _hookBIOS work?

Tags: assembly

I'm reading through The rootkit arsenal and came upon this code:

```
LEA DX, _hookBIOS
```

The comment says that it sets up the first ISR, which is previously defined as follows:

```
_install:  
LEA DX, _getBufferAddr
MOV CX, CS
MOV DS, CX
MOV AH, 25H
MOV AL, 187
INT 21H
```

Can someone explain how the hookBIOS function works with respect to the install? Or can someone point me to some references where I can figure out the relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEA` just loads an address, it doesn't do anything else. Whatever set up is done is in other code you have omitted.

The `_install` is invoking dos function `25h` which is `set interrupt vector`. It expects the vector number in `AL`, so that's `187` in this case. The address is passed in `DS:DX`. Thus the `_install` sets up interrupt `187` to point to `_getBufferAddr`.